# Redux variable considered null yet appears in console

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am trying to render a homepage depending on user being connected or not.

**App.js**

```
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);    
   
    {!user ? <Login></Login> : (
    <div className="app__body">
      <Sidebar></Sidebar>
      <Feed></Feed>
      <Widget></Widget>
    </div>
  )}
```

**userSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: null
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});
export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;


export const selectUser = (state) => state.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**Login.js**

```
function Login() {
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const loginToApp = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(userAuth => {
    dispatch(
        login({
            email: userAuth.user.email,
            uid: userAuth.user.uid,
            displayName: userAuth.user.displayName,
            photoUrl: userAuth.user.photoURL,
        })
    )
}).catch(error => alert(error))
}
```

Though `<Login></Login>` is always being rendered, even if **user** is not null, I don't understand as in the redux console, **user** is not null.

[image]

Comment: I removed the angular tag..

Comment: Please share how you're extracting `user` out of the Redux state.

Comment: I've edited my original post, is this what you expected me to show ? ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my store name was wrong because I've npx created it with redux template and haven't changed store name from **counter** to **user**.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

It all works now.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot only includes the `render` part and the problem might not be `render`, I think. It must be related to the logic. For example, you might defined `user` as a `state` and use it.

To get help, I think you should check the part and show them, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not really sure about this. I think the problem is here.

```
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user;
```

According to [official document](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) you need to use `createSelector`.

So it should try like this.

```
export const selectUser = createSelector(
  (state) => state.user
)
...
const user = useSelector(selectUser);
```